# Product migration Magento 2.0.7 to Magento cloud 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2-cloud

What is the best way to migrate all products from Magento 2.0.7 to Magento Cloud 2.3.2?

I try to export all products from M2.0 and import with M2.3 with Magento import/export tool, but didn't work.

I this moment I have arround 3000 product to import (16 attribute set and several attributes that were already created in the M2.3).

There is any trick to do this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `didn't work` ?? please explain the error

Comment: Try this [Magento to Magento migration service](https://next-cart.com/product/magento-to-magento/). I believe they can help you.